# How do I save images from e-mail?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Running current Outlook as supplied via O365.  I sent myself a bunch of images from my phone so I could download them on the computer.  I can see them fine, but they are in-line.  If I go to save attachments there are none to save.  If I right click to copy them to try to paste and save elsewhere, I'm not allowed to copy.  If I save the entire message to disk it still saves it as one big thing (does not split out the images into a folder like older Outlook versions used to).  How can I extract these images from this e-mail and save them as individuals?

Comment: A screenshot will provide a visual explanation of what you see, and explain, your confusion

Comment: What do you mean by "they are none to save"?

Normally to save attachment, we can right click it and choose “Save As” or “Save All Attachments”.

Comment: Are there any errors when saving attachments？I find one similar thread here. You can check whether this is the case for you:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/105e23ca-ca53-406c-8bdf-c000cd0630e4/outlook-2016-cannot-save-message-and-attachement?forum=outlook

Comment: If I right click the image, there is no option to save.  If I go to the generic "Save attachments" dialog it's empty as if there are no attachments!

Comment: Can you log on the web mail to save the attachment?

Comment: Tested here. I can also drag and drop attachments to a local folder. For Outlook side, I'd like to recommend you create a new profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-lined images cannot be saved via right-click, as you've found out. This is the normal behavior for Outlook.

They can, however, be copied.

This is a manual process.

1. Right-click on the inlined image and select Copy.
2. Open an image editor application such as MS Paint.
3. Paste into a new blank image.
4. Save.

You could turn this into a macro if you have a lot of images to save. Outlook, like other Office products, supports the full Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) macro language and so you can program really cool things.

However, the better thing is to not use email to get pictures from your phone to your computer: either change the settings of your phone's mail client to attach the images rather than inlining/embedding them in the messages, or if possible use one of the myriad of file transfer/cloud drive solutions that offer image backup.

Comment: To clarify, this works from O365 webmail in the browser, so is a valid solution.  However, it does not work in the Outlook thick client!

Comment: It is supposed to work in the local full Outlook install. It is the method directed by Microsoft in their official help document for this issue. If it does not work in your Outlook full client you should check for updates, create a new Outlook profile, and/or perform a repair install of Outlook or Office.

Answer (score 2):

On my (I believe) current version of Outlook 365 on the desktop, a right click on an inline image does not give an option to save it, but if I ***left click first***, then right click, it *does* give a "Save as Picture..." option.

For saving all of the images, it's true that the default "Save as type" option, "Outlook Message Format - Unicode" saves the message in a single file, but if you choose the "HTML" option instead, it will create a folder with the images and other files in it.